# Dynamic DropDownList in Umbraco 7

Tags: drop-down-menu, umbraco7

How can i create a **dynamic dropdown** list in Umbraco 7. This dropdown items are going to populate through webservice.

Please suggest a way through i can create a **dynamic dropdownlist** in Umbraco 7.

Thanks

Abhishek

Comment: Do you mean `Dropdown` created by `Database` ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a dropdown list in the Umbraco backend, I would use a package called [nuPickers](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/nupickers/)

This plugin allows you to implement a [custom .Net provider](https://github.com/uComponents/nuPickers/wiki/Data-Source-DotNet) that enables you to populate it throug a webservice